# Window is not defined when bundling js files via webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am importing a third party javascript file. When building via webpack I am getting error as 'Window is not defined' . I am able to find the cause of this issue. The reason is when building this javascript file, execution is not happening in browser environment. But I am stuck with how to fix the issue. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/exenv package.

```
import ExecutionEnvironment from 'exenv';

if (ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM) {
    require("third-party-file.js");
}
```

Comment: You can use the `externals` config section in webpack to get the same result: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/